# logistic distribution

Tags: logistic-distribution

Is it true that almost every discrete data set containing positive values follow logistic distribution if the data set is log-transformed and standardised(subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation)?

Comment: Where did you hear such claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. One could give unlimited number of counterexamples, e.g. if distribution $X$ non-negative and bimodal, then after log-transformation the two modes would not collapse, while logistic distribution is not bimodal. If $Y$ follows standard [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distribution, then taking log of it would make the transformed variable follow normal distribution. Another example, basic way of sampling from logistic distribution is to take standard uniform variable $U$ and then $\log(U) - \log(1-U)$ is a standard logistic distribution, so it is not $\log$ alone.